# How can I run scalafmt automatically in project?

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I use [scalafmt](http://scalameta.org/scalafmt/) plugin in my project, also I use [scalafmt plugin for Intellj](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8236-scalafmt) in order to format my Scala code.
Usually I use hot keys or run `sbt scalafmt` to formatting.

```
sbt.version=1.0.3
addSbtPlugin("com.geirsson" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "1.3.0")
```

Question:
*Any advice how can I format code with scalafmt automatically on compile time?*

Comment: The IntelliJ plugin offers a setting to automatically format on save; did you see it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE:** just update the plugin version and use

```
scalafmtOnCompile := true
```

---

*The answer below is outdated, it recommended using an alternative plugin, but now it's another way round, the official one is up to date and supports this feature out of the box.*

From the scalafmt [installation instructions](http://scalameta.org/scalafmt/#sbt-scalafmt) for the plugin your use:

> The sbt plugin does not provide reformat on compile settings. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/olafurpg/e045ef9d8a4273bae3e2ccf610636d66) shows a DIY plugin to enable reformat on compile. YMMV.
>
> Why isn't that gist included in the sbt plugin? See [#597](https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt/issues/597).

I recommend you to try [neo-sbt-scalafmt](https://github.com/lucidsoftware/neo-sbt-scalafmt) instead. It's generally more configurable and better maintained (the other plugin is abandoned, see the issue linked above). With this plugin you can turn on formatting on compilation with simple

```
scalafmtOnCompile := true
```

See [docs](https://github.com/lucidsoftware/neo-sbt-scalafmt#task-configuration) for more options.